# DAO insert behavior doesnt seem normal

Tags: java, sql, dao

I made the DAO to create a sales offer and it is similar to an other DAO where it makes users and that connects and works. But the one below keeps skipping the if statements and I'm not sure why it isn't adding to the data base. I ran the same command in the SQL string in oracle and it worked there.

```
public boolean sendOffer(Sales sell) {

    boolean done = false;
    int key =0;
    Connection conn = cu.getConnection();
    try {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO sales (offer_amount, offer_who, car_id) values(?,?,?)";
        String[]keys= {"ID"};
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql,keys);
        ps.setInt(1, sell.getOfferAmount());
        ps.setInt(2, sell.getOwnerID());  //foriegn key
        ps.setInt(3, sell.getCarID()); // forgien key
        int number = ps.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(number!=1) 
        {
            log.warn("data insert fail");
        }
        else 
        {
            log.trace("success");
            done=true;
        }
           if(rs.next()) {
               key=rs.getInt(1);
               sell.setID(key);
               conn.commit();
               }
           else {
               log.warn("data not found");
           }


    }catch(SQLException e)
    {

    }
finally {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return done;
}'''
```

Comment: opps let me add one in there thanks.

Comment: Got this Error ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ADMIN.FK_SALES_CAR) violated - parent key not found.  ok im a dumb dumb I was trying to insert a Car id that didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that an exception is happening in your code but the try/catch block is intercepting it and swallowing it silently. While it may be tempting to catch and swallow exceptions, truth is it always causes more problems than it solves and the key concept of handling exceptions is to NOT handle them: just put the `throws` declaration and let the application crash.

You then have other possible side-issues depending on how the `Connection` was obtained in the first place, like the fact that you're never closing the `PreparedStatement` and the `ResultSet` (if the connection is closed, they are closed as well... but if the connection is returned to a pool then they are never going to be closed).

In general the above code tends to pack too much functionality in a single method and can quickly spiral out of control, so you might want to divide it in smaller chunks with clear individual responsibilities.

All of the above is common to observe wherever `Connection` and `PreparedStatement` are used directly, be it for maximum performance reasons or for lack of experience. Typically in web applications using the Spring framework this is solved through the use of a `JdbcTemplate` but I cannot assume that you are using Spring so I won't show its usage here.

At a minimum, I would modify your code roughly as follows:

```
public boolean sendOffer(Sales sell) {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = cu.getConnection();
        ps = prepareInsertOfferStatement(sell, conn);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        sell.setID(extractKey(rs));
        conn.commit();
        log.trace("success");
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex);  // this is actually probably bad. Consider putting a throws declaration and get rid of this catch
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        closeQuietly(rs, ps, conn);
    }
}

private void closeQuietly(AutoCloseable... objs) {
    for(AutoCloseable obj : objs) {
        try {
            obj.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // this is usually mostly safe to ignore. Maybe log a warning somewhere
        }
    }
}

private PreparedStatement prepareInsertOfferStatement(Sales sell, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO sales (offer_amount, offer_who, car_id) values(?,?,?)";
    String[] keys= {"ID"};
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql,keys);
    ps.setInt(1, sell.getOfferAmount());
    ps.setInt(2, sell.getOwnerID());  //foreign key
    ps.setInt(3, sell.getCarID()); // foreign key
    return ps;
}

private int extractKey(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    if(rs.next()) {
        return rs.getInt(1);
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("The statement did not return any generated key.");
    }
}
```

As you can see it's not shorter, but responsibilities are clearer and all objects are closed accordingly. Furthermore, it gives you nice reusable primitives to close connections and related objects and to extract the key from other inserts you will want to do. Further abstractions would allow you to obtain more primitives, but I think this is sufficient for you to get the gist of it.

Comment: Thank you! I found the problem when I inserted the print error in the catch statements. I was using a foreign key ID that didn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I read that. I posted an answer anyway as it may be useful for you to prevent being stuck on such problems due to exceptions being swallowed. Cheers!